# Could not find a Profile button in tensorboard after install profile-plugin

Tags: pip, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, profile

Tensorboard version: 2.3.0

before I install profile-plugin on Tensorboard:

[image]

so I followed that order:

```sh
pip install -U tensorboard-plugin-profile

> Successfully installed tensorboard-plugin-profile-2.3.0
```

and the next time, still find a Profile button in tensorboard

[image]

I tried to use this URL `http://localhost:6006/#profile` to open profile

but it shows No dashboards are active for the current data set.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem Analysis

Your problem sounds like you are using a **virtual environment**. Probably, you mixed up package installations within and outside of the environment.

For instance, you might have installed TensorBoard and the plugin in the virtual environment, but forgot activating the environment when calling TensorBoard. Therefore, another instance of TB (without the profile plugin) is called.

## Solution

Make sure you have installed

- Tensorflow
- TensorBoard
- the profile plugin

all within the virtual environment. When starting TensorBoard, be sure that the virtual environment is activated.

Within TensorBoard, you should then see the profiler in the dropdown menu. Beware that the order might have changed; you will find the profiler at the very bottom:
see [TB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK4IO.png). (Sorry, I'm new at StackOverflow and can not embed images yet.)
Alternatively, you can directly use your stated URL: http://localhost:6006/#profile

If this does not work within the virtual environment, you could try installing the above-listed things **outside** of your virtual environment. If you start TB outside of the virtual environment then, you should be able to use the profiler.

## Additional Remarks

Also make sure you are using the Chrome browser, as other browsers show some issues, especially with the profiler.