# Profile a predict call Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, profiler

I have a trained network that I'm using to predict image data. I would like to speed up the prediction, but I don't know how to run the tensorboard profiler on predict. I prefer not to rerun training to optimize because of model size. This is similar to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308924/how-to-profile-a-keras-predict-call-with-tensorboard), but I'm asking again because that question got no relevant answers.

When I follow [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_profiling_keras.ipynb) profiling example, I get a profile, but when I add a predict step with the same callback it doesn't profile the predict.

```
(previous lines are loading and setting up an MNIST model as in the linked colab)

tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logs,
                                                  histogram_freq = 1,
                                                  profile_batch='500,520')
model.fit(ds_train,
          epochs=2,
          validation_data=ds_test,
          callbacks = [tboard_callback]
          )
model.predict(ds_test,callbacks=[tboard_callback])
```

Environment:
Windows 10, python 3.8, tensorflow 2.2,  tensorboard_plugin_profile 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a workaround. Write a custom prediction loop and instrument it with a `tf.profiler.experimental.Trace` like described in [Profiling API section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSuAS.png) of the [Optimize TensorFlow performance using the Profiler guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler).